# Focus not set on menu item

Tags: wpf, user-controls, focus, menuitem

I have a menu on my view.  When focus on menu that time press <kbd>F1</kbd>.  This <kbd>F1</kbd> opens a browser page.  Now close the browser.  Focus not show on menu after closing the browser.  Focus should still remain on menu but it comes after pressing tab.

Comment: Please post the relevant code

Answer (score 1):

That is just a nature of Windows focus system. 
The focus is set to that "Window" at first. If you want to focus to menu, try `GotFocus` event on the root `<Window>`.

Comment: but it working on other controls like text box,button without using GotFocus event.